# How to add logging to Blazor Server-side component?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a hosted ASP.net Blazor application and trying to get a logger into my controller.

I have this:

```
public MyController(ILogger logger) {
    _logger = logger;
    // more initialization
}
```

But when I run it, I get:

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger' while attempting to activate 'MyApp.Server.Controllers.MyController'.
```

As there are a lot of log messages scrolling by, I guess Blazor already initializes a logger.

How do I access this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The non-generic `ILogger` is not registered with the service collection. Instead, you are supposed to inject a generic `ILogger<T>`. The generic type argument `T` is used to set up the *category name* that is linked with the logger instance. It allows you to easily see where a log call came from.

Usually, you specify the type that you are using the logger with as the generic type argument. So in your case, you would use `ILogger<MyController>`:

```
public MyController(ILogger<MyController> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}
```

Note that there is nothing special to server-side Blazor about this behavior. This is standard ASP.NET Core and the controller is also a normal ASP.NET Core controller.

Comment: Your answer is rather partial and incomplete, and may be wrong, depending on how you're going to complete it. This is not a server-side Blazor. It's rather client-side Blazor (hosted Blazor). Configuration of both types (client or server) on the server may differ enormously from each other, as for instance, server-side Blazor may define its own logging system as part of employing SignalR, while client-side Blazor is not automatically providing any logging support, unless you ask for it. Do you see my point ? To make your answer complete, provide configuration of the DI container. Thanks...

Comment: @Issac If you look at the question, you will see that there is a *controller*, something that exists completely outside of Blazor (regardless of whether it is server-side or client-side). So since the question is not actually about Blazor, I am ignoring it completely for my answer except from the remark at the end.

Comment: I removed the Blazor tag from my original question. Since I am new to this, I couldn't tell it apart, but now I know. You are right, my question was about logging on the server-side part of hosted Blazor which is ASP.NET Core.